# generate_series dynamic transpose postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

Questions about transpose are asked many times before, but I cannot find any good answer when using generate_series in combination with a certain "boolean" query.

The output from generate series is:

```
2015-12-01
2015-12-02
2015-12-03
... and so on
```

My question is to find if the job start and stop fits into a certain date
like:

```
INSERT INTO job (id, start, stop) VALUES
(11, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-10'),
(22, '2015-12-01', '2015-12-02'),
(33, '2015-12-03', '2015-12-04');
```

But the job11 should not appear:

```
        2015-12-01  2015-12-02  2015-12-03  ...and so on
job22        1          1          0
job33        0          0          1
```

The problem is that it has to be dynamical because the date range can vary. An lame attempt to solve this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a776b/37

**Updated question**

It seems that crosstab maybe should do the trick, but I only get errors:

```
select * from crosstab('select generate_series(1,3)')
as ct (a int2,b int2,c int2)
```

> ERROR: The provided sql must return 3 columns rowid, categories and values

What am I doing wrong? There is no such columns in generate_series.

**Updated question #2**

In this way I get no errors, but the output is not the desired.

```
select * from crosstab('select i::int2,i::int2,i::int2 from      
generate_series(1,3) i')
as ct (a int2,b int2,c int2)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNrx7.png

Comment: Use `crosstab()` function to achieve this.

Comment: function crosstab(unknown) does not exist on sqlfiddle. Add extension?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a776b/42  How do I create dynamic columns?

Comment: You need to use `plpgsql` - wrap it up in a function to do that. There's no way to dynamically do this using plain `SQL`.

Comment: But crosstab() should work with plain SQL?

Comment: Why do you need the values as columns?  You can readily generate what you want as rows.

Comment: I've never said it doesn't work with plain `SQL`. The thing is, if you want to have dynamically generated list of column names assigned (the `AS (...)` clause) then you need procedural language for this.

Comment: Each column should be presented in a "gantt" type view. Previously I have transposed them by the frontend, but it is very slow.

Comment: Look into `crosstab(text, text)` and `functions`. As to your updated query, there is such column: `select i,i,i from generate_series(1,3) i`

Comment: I cannot find any clue how generates_series() is constructed with crosstab(text, text). There is only one column in generate_series.

Comment: @ConsiderMe "if you want to have dynamically generated list of column names assigned (the AS (...) clause) then you need". Yes, but I can do this in my front end tool and paste as plain text in the query. It should be fast enough to do in a for loop.

Comment: Please tell me why `job11` shouldn't appear? Do you mean that it should be excluded as in `WHERE` condition? I will try to find the time to answer your question which will include dynamic number of columns depending on your `generate_series()` output.

Comment: @ConsiderMe "Please tell me why job11 shouldn't appear?" it could appear, but with zeros on every day, because it is out of range (november).